# Laravel: Is it possible to log stack trace every request?

Tags: php, laravel, stack-trace

I want to log every request with a full stack trace on laravel. Just like laravel error exception tracing. Is there anything available on laravel or any third-party packages?

We already use laravel telescope, but the telescope doesn't give us full stack trace.tracing

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction

Comment: @DanielL we wants to store full request trace of all request.

Comment: You can create your own middleware with debug_print_backtrace

Answer (score 2):

Stack traces are bound to PHP exceptions (or errors, warnings, etc) as they *trace* the way through your application execution stack up to this particular exception.

So you need to decide for a good point that is deep in the stack where your application logic as already been executed. In that place, just throw an exception, catch it and use the report() helper to log the exception.

E.g. you can't just throw this at the end of `public/index.php`

```php
try {
    throw new \Exception('my breakpoint');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    report($e);
    return false;
}
```

because the stacktrace would just consist of one line (as the exception is thrown at the top level).

You could try creating a new middleware that throws this exception and make that middleware last in your request middlewares.